# Do I unregister/unregister ContentObserver in Loaders to avoid memory leaks

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have many loader classes that extends Loader class. I have a ForceContentObserver in that class.
Now I am using MatrixCursor in my some of the loaders which I am registering using the code:

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(uri, true, mObserver);
cursor.registerContentObserver(mObserver);
```

Do I have to unregister content observer from the loader when my fragment/activity pauses to avoid memory leaks?
The blog post [here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/) states that content observers must be unregistered otherwise the activity/fragment may not be garbage collected.

This point is valid when we pass the activity context or when we are working on the activity/fragment level.
But I found that Loader internally keeps a reference of Application context object. This means the chances of memory leak is not present. So all the code of registering/unregistering the obsevers is it really necessary?

Comment: no need for custom loaders: see http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/CursorLoader.java#70

Comment: I know CursorLoader, but we had to add our own logic to the AsyncTask of the CursorLoader which is why we wrote our own loader. The code is based on the CursorLoader. I just have question regarding memory leakage.

Comment: still have no idea why you want to `registerContentObserver` ? who is going to `notifyChange` ?

Comment: The notifyChange is done through the ContentProvider during the insert and update operation for the particular uri.

Comment: so why do you want to use it in your custom loader: `contentResolver.registerContentObserver(uri, true, mObserver);` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86823/discussion-between-kanishk-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

[`LoaderManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.html) will actually keep a limited set of loaders (no duplicates). At the same time, it is probably a good idea to unregister (despite cursorloader not doing so) as observers are stored in a plain ArrayList (not a with [WeakReferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)). The best place to do so is in [`Loader.onStopLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html#onStopLoading()) (and perhaps [`Loader.onAbandon()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html#onAbandon())) as at that point the loader should not provide further change notifications. [`LoaderManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.html) will call these functions at appropriate times.